# Listing an array in a message

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js

I want to list an array in a discord message. I've got the following code so far:

```
message.channel.send("Game is starting with " + playerNumber + " Players! \n"
    + memberIDs.forEach(element => ("<@" + element + "> \n")));
```

The `memberIDs` array contains all IDs from member in a specific channel, now I want to put all member who are in the channel into a message. I've tried it with the code above but it only gives me the message:

```
Game is starting with *playerNumber* Players!
undefined
```

I don't really understand why it is undefined because it also would give me the memberIDs in a console log or when I make a forEach loop with messages that get created for every memberID.

The Array in the console.log locks like the following:

```
[ '392776445375545355', '849388169614196737' ]
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You're looking for `.map`, not `.forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**short answer**
`forEach()` is not your friend; you need to `map()` and `join()`

**long answer**
the `undefined` is the result of the `forEach()` invocation which does not return anything.

so you need to get an string instead.

to do so, you may use `.map()` which returns an array; and `.join()` that joins an array of strings into an string.

something like this:

```
memberIDs.map(element => "<@" + element + ">" ).join('\n');
```

Comment: You should probably fix the invalid syntax where you have a backtick and a quote for the `.join()`

Comment: ooops you're right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` iterates over an array and doesn't return anything. Use `map` instead with `join`:

```
message.channel.send("Game is starting with " + playerNumber + " Players! \n"
    + memberIDs.map(element => `<@${element}>`).join('\n')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array of return values from the callback, while [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. Use `.map()`

```js
memberIDs.map(m => `<@${m}>`)
.join("\n") // join each element with a newline
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't return anything in JavaScript, meaning that `memberIDs.forEach(element => ("<@" + element + "> \n")))` will always be undefined.

```js
let idString = "";

memberIDs.forEach(element => (idString = idString + "<@" + element + "> \n"))

message.channel.send("Game is starting with " + playerNumber + " Players! \n"
    + idString);
```

What this code does is it defines a variable outside of the `forEach` loop, and then appends strings to it each time the loop runs.